# Average area of a random triangle inscribed in a semicircle

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Let's say we have a triangle lying inside a semicircle ($R=1$), two vertices on the diameter ($x= \pm 1,~~y=0$), while the third somewhere on the circle in the first quadrant.

It's pretty basic stuff, I just wanted to check if I'm doing this correctly.

[image]

The area of any such triangle is:

$$S=\frac{1}{2} 2R y=y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

1) The distribution of vertex positions is constant in $x$ on $x \in (0,1)$.

$$f(x)=1$$

$$<S>=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}~ dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

2) The distribution is constant in $y$ on $y \in (0,1)$.

$$<S>=\int_0^1 y~ dy=\frac{1}{2}$$

3) The distribution is constant in polar angle $\phi$ for $\phi \in (0, \pi/2)$.

$$f(\phi)=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

$$S=\sin \phi$$

$$<S>=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin \phi~d \phi=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

So am I doing this correct? I wanted to check if my basics are right, before moving on to more complicated probability problems

Comment: They are right, and well written up.  As is often the case in geometric probability, the answer depends heavily on how one defines "random triangle."

Comment: Andre is correct.  Random triangle is not a well defined term.  You could define it by selecting a random point on the circle which would give you a different distribution.  Basically you have to pick a definition of random triangle and stick with it.

Comment: I agree with all 3 answers - good job!

Comment: I disagree slightly with André: the write up is not entirely clear. You write $f(x)=1$ and $f(\phi)=2/\pi$, for example, but you have not told us what $f(x)$ and $f(\phi)$ are, and you didn't write anything for $f(y)$. You aren't wrong, but you should define your notation.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, the probability distributions, I thought it followed from the preceding lines

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I still have to read the textbook though, because I'm having trouble with two-dimensional distributions

Comment: I know they're the probability distributions, but only because I had to guess, and you didn't write down the distribution for $y$.

Comment: 3) is also equivalent to the angle at the left vertex being uniformly distributed in $(0,\frac{\pi}{4})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As stated in various comments, all three results are correct.

A distribution is more usually said to be "uniform" rather than "constant".